# Help filling parent container space dynamically dependent on content

Tags: javascript, html, css

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SedpW/20/embedded/result/)

I want the numbers to take up all the blue space in the jsFiddle. The numbers can change, so I dont think this is possible to solve in css. The "days" value can be a 3 or 4 digit number, so when the days changes from say 2 to 3 digits I need it to re-calculate margins etc to fill up the container(blue box). By fill up the parent I mean that there should not be any empty space to the left or right of the numbers.

What is the best approach for this problem?

Comment: So you want to justify the `li` elements so that the rightmost one touches the right edge, and they all have the same amount of space in between? Which browsers/versions do you need to support?

Comment: yes I want the li elements to take up all the space. And yeah all modern browsers

Comment: Would you be opposed to resizing the containing element (the red box), or are you trying to keep that width fixed?

Comment: the red box is the wrapper, I dont want to change its width

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind counting on javascript then [FitJS](http://fittextjs.com) might help you, it's a jquery plugin that sizes text to the width of its container. Though you might need to tweak the html a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `text-align:justify` and `display:inline-block` with a helper to make he preceding items to justify: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/SedpW/22/embedded/result/

So, with different numbers it would look like: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/SedpW/23/embedded/result/

And if you'll need ie7- support, don't forget to fix `inline-block` in it adding in conditional comments

```
display:inline;
zoom:1;
```

to the blocks where you want the `inline-block` to be fixed.